# WPF. How to make a binding into Brush to property of ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I made control. Here is the code:

```cs
public class ShutterWidget : Control
{ // this Control changes own Background property (changes brush) in some time }
```

And ResourceDictionary with style for it:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:widgets="clr-namespace:ProcessControl.Widgets">

    <DrawingBrush x:Key="ShutterBrush" x:Shared ="true"  Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Geometry="F1M84.7698,0.8018L84.7698,36.1568 106.761,14.2929 106.761,0.8018 84.7698,0.8018z"/>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1M84.7698,0.8018L84.7698,36.1568 106.761,14.2929 106.761,0.8018 84.7698,0.8018z">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="Black" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" StartLineCap="Round" Thickness="1.6036"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>

    <Style TargetType="widgets:ShutterWidget">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="widgets:ShutterWidget">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource ShutterBrush}"/>    
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This dictionary include template for display this Control. This template uses DrawingBrush.

I want to change of fill of the parts of DrawingBrush by changing the background property of ShutterWidget.

UPDATE:

I went another way, because it seems to me to change parts of DrawingBrush difficult. I decided change whole DrawingBrush on another. But now I got one more problem.
I created different ResourceDictionary and each includes one DrawingBrush. From code behind I load them using XamlReader.Load. But XamlReader throw exception " Failed to create "ImageSource" text-based "valve_off_files/image0.png". Directory "valve_off_files" includes extra png files( I get ResourceDictionary from emf file using ExpressionDesign. It creates xaml file and extra directory with extra image file.). And when I load XamlReader doesn't find extra file image0.png which is used in DrawingBrush.
Why doesn't XamlReader see this file image0.png?

Below is a part of code from ResourceDictionary which was created ExpressionDesign.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="valve_off" Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <ImageDrawing ImageSource="valve_off_files/image0.png" Rect="0,0,88,96"/>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
```

And so I load xaml files:

```cs
    public static Brush GetItem(string name)
    {
        using (var str = new FileStream($"Resources/{name}.xaml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var dct = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(str);
            return (Brush)dct?[name];
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 2:

I found a solution. I was helped using of other method of XamlReader which accept ParserContext. XamlReader.Load(FileStream, ParserContext). After I set BaseUri property of ParserContext, XamlReader has read xaml file correctly.

Thanks to a lot all people who tried to help me.

Comment: is your DrawingBrush dictionnary referenced somewhere (in app.xaml or generic). ? did you get any error message ?

Comment: This both are into one resourceDictionary. When I put that brush into style in Rectangle.Fill it works( for example <Rectangle.Fill><DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform"> etc. ) About error message i have nothing. It runs and just display without color

Comment: may be test change that to any color- <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"

Comment: if I change Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" for example on Brush="#FFFFFFFF" - control is drawn this color but I need to get this value from Background property of control which apply this style. Sorry for my English)

Comment: I think you will need to show some more code.  If you put the code you have into a single window XAML file and target some control like a textbox, it seems to work.

Comment: good, it seems that this <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" is not working the your separated styles. try <GeometryDrawing Brush="{TemplateBinding Background}" or have to set the <Style TargetType="widgets:ShutterWidget"><<Setter Property="Background"=?

Comment: But I've read that TemplateBinding can be use only into ControlTemplate.